# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, api, laravel, foreach

I am using laravel 5.2 and I want to display data on my dropdown/list of view from api. but I have got an error Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). This is my function:

```
public function MyFunction()
{
    $datadropdown= Requests::get('http://WebService/api/dropdown.php?access_token=DFiXxl7jKGS5VkAwsdfxBi9CTeCfasdcxvew9HW1kPt');

    $getData = ['datadropdown' => $datadropdown->body];

    return view('myview', $getData);
}
```

and this is in the blade view:

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true">
    @foreach($datadropdown as $dw) 
        <option value="{{ $dw->KODE }}"> {{ $dw->DESKRIPSI }} </option> 
    @endforeach
</select>
```

When I `print_r` the `$datadropdown->body` the output is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do like this, You passed getData to view

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true">
    @foreach($getData as $dw) 
        <option value="{{ $dw->KODE }}"> {{ $dw->DESKRIPSI }} </option> 
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I have tried that before and get the error `Undefined variable: getData`

Comment: Pass like this: return view('myview')->with('getData', $getData);

Comment: The error now is `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: @hendraspt I assume you're doing `Model::where(something)->first()`? Null can be returned which will eventually result in property of non object.

Comment: I think your data in json format, decode it first json_decode($getData) and try

Comment: @Andrew @Komal I have solved this issue with `$data=json_decode($datadropdown ['datadropdown ']);
        return view('myview')->with('datadropdown ', $data->wilayah[0]->data);` @Komal was right, the data is in json format and i have to decode it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you see, you have `data` array inside of `wilayah`.

So yo can do this:

```
$getData = ['datadropdown' => $datadropdown->body->wilayah->data];
```